# How to make an API call to Youtube using meteor

Tags: meteor, youtube, youtube-data-api, youtube-javascript-api, meteor-blaze

I am trying to make an API call to

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions
```

I'm trying to make it so when a user logs in using google-accounts they will be able to see their YouTube subscription list. It is currently not working at I am not sure why.

Im getting two errors in the console:

1.

`www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&mine=true&key=MYKEY&part=snippet&mine=true:1 
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&…ne=true&key=MYKEY&part=snippet&mine=true 401 (OK)`

2.

```
Object {statusCode: 401, content: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "gl…e": 401,↵  "message": "Invalid Credentials"↵ }↵}↵", headers: Object, data: Object}content: "{↵ "error": {↵  "errors": [↵   {↵    "domain": "global",↵    "reason": "authError",↵    "message": "Invalid Credentials",↵    "locationType": "header",↵    "location": "Authorization"↵   }↵  ],↵  "code": 401,↵  "message": "Invalid Credentials"↵ }↵}↵"data: Objectheaders: ObjectstatusCode: 401__proto__: Object
```

My code looks as followed:

```
//client side

Meteor.autosubscribe(function(){
  var newUser = Meteor.user();
  Meteor.subscribe('currentAccessToken');
});

var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/subscriptions?part=subscriberSnippet&mine=true&key=key";
var options = {
  'headers' : {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + "currentAccessToken",
    'X-JavaScript-User-Agent': "Google APIs Explorer"
    },
    'params' : {
       part : 'snippet',
       mine : 'true',
    }
};

    var searchResult =   HTTP.call("get", url,options,
        function (error, result) {
            if (!error) {
              Session.set("twizzled", true);
            }
            console.log(result);

        });
```

On the server side I am publishing the access token so that it can be sent with the GET request

```
//Server Side

  Meteor.publish("currentAccessToken", function(){
  return Meteor.users.find(this.userId, {fields: {'services.google.accessToken': 1}});
});
```

I greatly appreciate any help or documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check would be authorization scopes. You have to explicitly add YouTube scope (more than one, actually, each defining single action or a small bunch of actions). To do that, you can use `Accounts` global object. Just add this code anywhere on the client side (inside `client` folder):

```
Accounts.ui.config({
  requestPermissions: {
    google: [
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube',
      'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.upload'
    ]
  }, 
  requestOfflineToken: {
    google: true
  }
});
```

The next time you authorize with Google, you should see that the popup asks not only for basic information but for YouTube access. For more information about YouTube Google API scopes, see [official docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos).